# Why do I get this error and how can I fix it? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, arc4random

I am making a guess the card game and i get this weird error which I cannot fix when I create a random number for the symbols and the card numbers. This is the error:

[An image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBqcQ.png)

```
let cardSymbols = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
let numbers = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

func getRandomCard() {

    var correctSymbolNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardSymbols.count - 1))
    var correctNumberNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numbers.count - 1))

    var correctSymbol = cardSymbols[correctSymbolNumber]
    var correctNumber = numbers[correctNumberNumber]

}
```

How can I fix this? I know the problem is with my arc4random... but how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the result of arc4random_uniform to a swift Int, currently it is a UInt32 which you cannot use for a swift dictionary or array.

So:

```
var correctSymbolNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardSymbols.count - 1)))
var correctNumberNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numbers.count - 1)))

var correctSymbol = cardSymbols[correctSymbolNumber]
var correctNumber = numbers[correctNumberNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the value of arc4random_uniform UInt32 to Int. as you can see this is the prototype of `arc4random_uniform` function which returns UInt32 
    `func arc4random_uniform(_: UInt32) -> UInt32`

```
var correctSymbolNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cardSymbols.count - 1)))
var correctNumberNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numbers.count - 1)))
```

also don't forget the unwrap the`correctSymbolNumber` and `correctNumberNumber` values.